# superagent doesn't return set-cookie header

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, superagent

I am using superagent to POST login data to my external endpoint (at a different origin). This external endpoint returns a JWT, as well as a set-header cookie with the JWT inside it as well. I use this cookie to render pages server-side if a user is already logged in.

However, when I check

```
request.end((err, res) => {
  console.log(res)
}
```

I do not see any set-header cookie. What am I doing wrong? If it helps, I am using [this boilerplate's](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) ApiClient.js.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `set-cookie` is one of the two [forbidden response header names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name).

Comment: Any idea why? Seems very strange.

Comment: The link that @Knu posted contains an explanation.